# Multi-threading recursive functions in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, python-multithreading, variadic

### Background:

I am working on Telecoms Network discovery script, that is run by crontab on linux. It uses a seed file of initial network nodes, it connects to them, get all neighbors and then connects to those neighbors and so on and so on. Typical recursion. 
To speed up the whole thing I was using Multi-threading with Semaphore, so I had only certain number of running threads, but huge number of started threads, waiting. At certain point I run into maximum thread limit of linux so the script was not able to start new threads.

### Problem:

In pursuit of a design, that would allow multi-threading of this recursion it seemed to me its a case of multi hybrid producer/consumer scenario. Multiple consumers are also producing.

Consumer takes item from queue, consumes it and if there are any results, returns each result into the queue again.

To make it really nice I would like to create design pattern, that is usable for any type of recursion function, in other words with any args and kwargs.

What I expect from such function is, that I pass it any combination of variables(args, kwargs) that it needs and I get in return list of arguments, that I can pass to it again in other recursions.

### Questions:

- Is there any better way to handle getting args, kwargs from function return other than the one I used? I basically created a tuple (args, kwargs) (tuple(), dict()), that the func returns and Worker splits it into args, kwargs afterwards. Ideal would be to not need to create that tuple at all.
- Would you have any other improvement tips on this design?

Thank you sincerely!

---

### Current Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from queue import Queue, Empty
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from random import choice, random


class RecursiveWorkerThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, name, pool):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.pool = pool
        self.tasks = pool.tasks
        self.POISON = pool.POISON
        self.daemon = False
        self.result = None
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        print(f'WORKER {self.name} - is awake.')
        while True:
            if not self.tasks.empty():
                # take task from queue
                try:
                    func, f_args, f_kwargs = self.tasks.get(timeout=1)

                    # check for POISON
                    if func is self.POISON:
                        print(f'WORKER {self.name} - POISON found. Sending it back to queue. Dying...')
                        self.pool.add_task(self.POISON)
                        break

                    # try to perform the task on arguments and get result
                    try:
                        self.result = func(*f_args, **f_kwargs)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)

                    # recursive part, add results to queue
                    print(f'WORKER {self.name} - FUNC: ({func.__name__}) IN: (args: {f_args}, kwargs: {f_kwargs}) OUT: ({self.result}).')
                    for n_args, n_kwargs in self.result:
                        self.pool.add_task(func, *n_args, **n_kwargs)

                    # mark one task done in queue
                    self.tasks.task_done()
                except Empty:
                    pass
            sleep(random())


class RecursiveThreadPool:

    def __init__(self, num_threads):
        self.tasks = Queue()
        self.POISON = object()

        print('\nTHREAD_POOL - initialized.\nTHREAD_POOL - waking up WORKERS.')

        self.workers = [RecursiveWorkerThread(name=str(num), pool=self) for num in range(num_threads)]

    def add_task(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        if func is not self.POISON:
            print(f'THREAD_POOL - task received: [func: ({func.__name__}), args: ({args}), kwargs:({kwargs})]')
        else:
            print('THREAD_POOL - task received: POISON.')
        self.tasks.put((func, args, kwargs))

    def wait_for_completion(self):
        print('\nTHREAD_POOL - waiting for all tasks to be completed.')

        self.tasks.join()

        print('\nTHREAD_POOL - all tasks have been completed.\nTHREAD_POOL - sending POISON to queue.')

        self.add_task(self.POISON)

        print('THREAD_POOL - waiting for WORKERS to die.')

        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.join()

        print('\nTHREAD_POOL - all WORKERS are dead.\nTHREAD_POOL - FINISHED.')


# Test part
if __name__ == '__main__':

    percentage = [True] * 2 + [False] * 8

    # example function
    def get_subnodes(node):
        maximum_subnodes = 2
        sleep(5 * random())
        result_list = list()
        for i in range(maximum_subnodes):
            # apply chance on every possible subnode
            if choice(percentage):
                new_node = node + '.' + str(i)
                # create single result
                args = tuple()
                kwargs = dict({'node': new_node})
                # append it to the result list
                result_list.append((args, kwargs))
        return result_list


    # 1) Init a Thread pool with the desired number of worker threads
    THREAD_POOL = RecursiveThreadPool(10)

    # 2) Put initial data into queue
    initial_nodes = 10
    for root_node in [str(i) for i in range(initial_nodes)]:
        THREAD_POOL.add_task(get_subnodes, node=root_node)

    # 3) Wait for completion
    THREAD_POOL.wait_for_completion()
```

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that your thread pool isn't gaining you more performance and is instead likely hurting performance. As far as actually executing python code goes, you have to contend with the Global Interpreter Lock, which makes it so that only one thread can execute python code at a time.

Can you do some benchmarks between your version and what the code would look like synchronously? Chances are the best design here is just going to be to _not_ do it.

Comment: For reviews of working code, check out [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead of StackOverflow

Comment: @EthanMcCue Because I am doing ssh connection and extracting data through it, it takes time, similarly to the random sleep in example, that's why even multi-threading saves me a lot of time and speeds up my script at least five times. You are right, that if it would be only on the script itself, it would not be more efficient. Even the GIL does not bother me, because the time to process data is insignificant to the time to get them.

Comment: This should be moved to code review as stated above, but perhaps something like asyncio would be helpful.